# Service broker for kubernetes catalog, simple implementation for google cloud shell

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, service-broker, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to implement Azure osba service broker on google cloud shell to interact with google cloud kubernetes and Azure services, but i am not able to run it and always commands are ending in some error.

I have installed helm and service catalog also. Please suggest me any simple service broker for google cloud shell which i can implement easily for demo purpose.  Can i use Google shell cloud MySQL ( GCP)? Please provide any information in form of website link or github.

Comment: Are you trying to connect google cloud kubernetes to Azure services?
What are the steps that you have performed to do so?
However if you are trying to access GCP services from your Kubernetes Cluster, use [Config Connector](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/overview) as Google Cloud Platform [Service Broker](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/google-cloud-platform-service-broker) is deprecated

Comment: I have just used gcloud compute zone and region setup ,cluster setup ,helm command setup ,svc catalog install and then downloaded service broker  osba ( azure service broker from github) .But ,it was asking for Azure credentials . I am trying this ,created azure account . But i want some simple example, currently working on Google pub-sub using python.Can i consider pub sub as good example of service broker ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use [config connector](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/overview) to manage your Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resources through Kubernetes configuration as [Google cloud platform service broker](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/google-cloud-platform-service-broker) is deprecated. 
This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/getting-started) will help you to get started with config connector by managing a cloud spanner instance. You can also refer to this [repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-config-connector) that contains sample applications and resources like PubSub for use with Config Connector